# Getting "Cannot read property 'getContext' of null inside partial HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, html5-canvas

I'm building a HTML5 color wheel in a canvas element. I'm using AngularJS to generate individual pages. With the source code for generating the canvas in a separate file, I thought I'd be fine, since the `index` of my HTML refers to it. Since that failed to work (getting the error above), I resorted to placing it inside a JavaScript file that acts as the controller for this HTML partial. I end up getting the exact same error.

Here's the partial's AngularJS in question:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('careApp.tMain', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/tMain', {
    templateUrl: './templates/tMain.html',
    controller: 'tMainCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('tMainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      //Draw color wheel inside canvas
      var canvas = document.getElementById("picker");
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var x = canvas.width / 2;
      var y = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 100;
      var counterClockwise = false;

      for(var angle=0; angle<=360; angle+=1){
        var startAngle = (angle-2)*Math.PI/180;
        var endAngle = angle * Math.PI/180;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x, y);
        context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
        context.closePath();
        var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, radius);
        gradient.addColorStop(0,'hsl('+angle+', 10%, 100%)');
        gradient.addColorStop(1,'hsl('+angle+', 100%, 50%)');
        context.fillStyle = gradient;
        context.fill();
      }
  $scope.dimmer = 100;
});
```

For the HTML, all you need to know is that the partial has the following `canvas` element:

```
<canvas id="picker" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

`index.html` contains all of the external scripts and the main div that holds every partial inside it. The main application JS is also present, but it merely exists to load plugins and dependencies.

Has this been set up incorrectly? Do I need to try a different approach?

Comment: Can you please post a working solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a directive for your canvas element and then within the directive link function you would have access to the element directly and not use the id.

The issue your experiencing is probably because the partial for your page is loading after your controller is hit for the first time so the element cannot be found. `var canvas = document.getElementById("picker");` is returning null because it can't find the element, so the `getContext` will not work.

Comment: That was my suspicion - thanks for the help with the directive idea!